# How do I use Python 3.0 under Apache?

Tags: python, windows, apache, python-3.x

I've searched for ages on how to use Python 3 under Apache. If there is a walkthrough anywhere, it's very well hidden. Thus, hopefully, one of you Python professionals could make a quick 1-2-3 on how it's done!

I'm on Windows 7 using the newest version of XAMPP.

Comment: Must I really ask you to elaborate on the downvote?

Comment: Upvoted :} Good, sensible question, maybe a bit better suited for superuser, but it's fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Python 3 and Django with Apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930585/how-to-use-python-3-and-django-with-apache)

Comment: please do not duplicate your own questions. You can edit your original post to clarify your question.

Comment: You really don't want to use Python 3.0 (end-of-life since the 3.1 release!) - get 3.1 or even 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only on Python 3.1:

> http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.0 is only supported via CGI. Put your CGI script in `cgi-bin\`. If you're willing to look at newer versions, preliminary support is available in mod_wsgi (but you'll probably have to build it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write Python 3 WSGI apps try [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/RunOnPython3k). I prefer nginx & uwsgi myself.